# Is dynamical localisation an interference effect?

Tags: condensed-matter, interference, tight-binding, floquet-theory

The question refers to the well-known phenomenon of **dynamical localisation** due to an oscillating electric field, as explained in [Dunlap & Kenkre, PRB 34,6 (1986)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.34.3625). Here, a particle initially localised to a single lattice site will remain localised if the ratio of field amplitude to driving frequency equals the root of the zeroth Bessel function of the first kind (e.g. 2.405).

There are several other types of localisation phenomena that can occur on a tight-binding lattice (no interactions) and I would like to know how to relate these to one another.

For instance, localisation can result from **destructive interference**, either due to a specific geometry (such as a flat band in the Kagome or Lieb lattices), or due to disorder (Anderson localisation). On the contrary, particles can simply become **"trivially"** localised due to a strong lattice confinement (zero tunnelling amplitude, "deep lattice").

**First question: is dynamical localisation an interference effect?**

On the one hand, after reading the original paper I would attribute dynamical localisation to an interference effect and thus relate it closely to the other interference-type localisation effects (geometry or disorder). Is this correct? Alternatively, there could exist a classical analogue of dynamical localisation that I might not be aware of and the effect has nothing to do with interference (there is a PRL that argues along these lines [10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.174101](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.6325)).

On the other hand, I can describe dynamical localisation on a tight-binding lattice with an effective band structure in the high-frequency limit in which tunnelling $t$ becomes $t\times \mathcal{J}_0(E/\omega)$, i.e. 'renormalised' as people like to say (why?) by the zeroth Bessel function of $E$ (field amplitude) over $\omega$ (drive frequency). This sounds more like infinitely deep potential barriers and the trivial kind of localisation.

**Second question: is the physical origin of dynamical localisation important?**

Are there any physical (i.e. measurable) phenomena that explicitly rely on the physical origin of the localisation, dynamical or other? For instance, maybe dynamical localisation behaves differently in the presence of interactions, compared simply to a deep lattice? Or else, maybe in a tight-binding lattice there is no measurable difference between different types of localisation but in a more realistic lattice there would be?